# maven not building parent pom

Tags: java, maven-3

i have included a parent pom for the child pom ..but while building the child pom..instead of building the parent..it tries to download it from repository and gives error that could not download it and thus fails.
This is the child pom:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mygroup1</groupId>
        <artifactId>base</artifactId>
        <relativePath>../Base/pom.xml</relativePath>
        <version>1.0</version>
   </parent>



  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mygroup2.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>client</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>some-version</version>
```

and the base pom is as:

```
<groupId>com.mygroup1</groupId>
  <artifactId>base</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
```

On building the child first before the parent..instead of building the parent it gives this error: `Could not find artifact com.mygroup1:base:pom:1.0 in <artifactory name>`
So should the parent be built first explicitly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How exactly is your project structured? This will only work, if it's part of an aggregator. Merely specifying a `<parent/>` wouldn't automatically make Maven build it, it would simply tell it which parent to use. If, on the other hand, both the parent and the child modules are defined as `<modules/>` in an aggregator, the parent will get built first.

Also, if you have an aggregator, but you are only trying to build from within the child module, the parent will not be built.

Comment: thanks carlspring..i was under the impression that parent would build first in any case..in case of aggregator it does build first.